# Coded UI Test is not recognized by Test Explorer?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

## GOAL

Build and run a Coded UI Test (the "CUIT").

## ENVIRONMENT

- Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate
- Three websites and one CUIT project in one solution.

[image: CUIT Solution]

- Two startup projects. One is the application logic and the other is the interface.

[image: CUIT Startup Projects]

- Successful recording of a CUIT available.

[image: Successful CUIT]

## PROBLEM

The Test Explorer doesn't recognize the test **and** running all tests **does nothing.**

[image: CUIT Test Explorer]

## WHAT I'VE TRIED

- Rebuilding the entire solution by right-clicking on the solution and selecting rebuild.
- Rebuilding the entire solution by pressing <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+B</kbd>.
- Click Tests -> Run -> All Tests

[image: CUIT Tests-Run-All Tests]

## CONCLUSION

In the end, the bottom line, I can't get Visual Studio to recognize this test. I'm not in a position to build unit tests because I'm maintaining an old application that's just not built for unit tests - but I need to get some automated regression testing into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a recording, but not yet an actual test. When you generate code for the recording, it should generate the actual CodedUI test. That should be picked up by the Test Explorer.

Comment: I ended up having to write those tests on my own, which is okay actually, because I was able to build small units that can be reused so my tests can run continually (e.g. navigate back to root URL, login, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You made sure that the Test Methods had

```
  [TestMethod]
```

above them